# Right click not working on 18.04 Dell Inspiron 15 3000

Tags: touchpad, dell, 18.04

Since updating to 18.04 from 17.10 right click on the touchpad doesn't work however on an external mouse it works fine as does two finger tap on the touchpad. I have tried this under both x-org and wayland and the same happens.

Comment: Hi Neil.  Looks like this is reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libinput/+bug/1603183.  The config wants your machine to act like a Mac.  If you prefer the normal dell behavior, run this in a terminal: $ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method areas

Comment: Same issue with a DELL Inspiron 17 5000, solved thanks to PatKlig comment.

Comment: Thank you :) Actually found a switch in Tweaks, will teach me not to look through all the possible settings first.