# Right-click with dragging not working on Dell Touchpad since 18.04

Tags: touchpad, dell

I just upgraded from 17.10 to 18.04 and noticed that right-clicking on my touch-pad got recognized as left-click.

I'm using a Dell Inspiron 15 (new) with a touch-pad that has two separate physical click-buttons underneath (pressing harder than touching). I don't know if they're both wired to the same event, though.

Before the upgrade I could cause a right-click by either tipping with two fingers OR clicking the right physical button. I use the latter for navigating in 3D-GUIs or drawing programs.

After the upgrade only the two-finger-tap works. I cannot perform click-right-and-drag actions any more. The one-finger-tap-and-move for dragging with the primary key still works, but there's no two-finger-tap-and-move for dragging/drawing with the secondary key (wouldn't be very ergonomic anyway). Two-finger-moves get recognized as scroll-event, which I like.

I found some advises to get the old behavior back:

- [No secondary button (right click) on touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028776/no-secondary-button-right-click-on-touchpad?noredirect=1&lq=1&newreg=e482eabbc7034e12afc4dda78306a826)
- [Dell Vostro 3568 model ubuntu 17.04 touch-pad left and right click behaving same way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/957099/dell-vostro-3568-model-ubuntu-17-04-touch-pad-left-and-right-click-behaving-same)
- [Right click not working on 18.04 Dell Inspiron 15 3000](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1027583/right-click-not-working-on-18-04-dell-inspiron-15-3000)
- [Touchpad right click doesn't work on touchpad, only the buttons above it. Thinkpad E480 Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028757/touchpad-right-click-doesnt-work-on-touchpad-only-the-buttons-above-it-thinkp)
- [Right click not working on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029444/right-click-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But neither the "Area"- nor "Fingers"-mode allow me to issue a right-click by using the lower right corner of the pad.

I haven't tried the command-line suggestions from the above links, as they weren't really explained or looked like whatever the `Tweaks`-app does anyway.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a bug..